# Why image values are different in Matlab and OpenCV?

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have an original image:

[image]

I then read it, create a PSF, and blur it in Matlab:

```
lenawords1=imread('lenawords.bmp');
%create PSF
sigma=6;
PSFgauss=fspecial('gaussian', 8*sigma+1, sigma);

%blur it
lenablur1=imfilter(lenawords1, PSFgauss, 'conv');
lenablurgray1=mat2gray(lenablur1);
PSFgaussgray = mat2gray(PSFgauss);
```

and I saved the blurred image:

```
imwrite(lenablurgray1, 'lenablur.bmp');
```

When I display some values in it, I get

```
disp(lenablurgray1(91:93, 71:75))

0.5556    0.5778    0.6000    0.6222    0.6444
0.6000    0.6444    0.6667    0.6889    0.6889
0.6444    0.6889    0.7111    0.7333    0.7333
```

I then open that blurred image in OpenCV and display its values at the same indices:

```
Mat img = imread("lenablur.bmp");

for (int r = 91; r < 94; r++) {
    for (int c = 71; c < 76; c++) {
        cout << img.at<double>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

The result I get doesn't match the values above:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Why is this?

**EDIT**:  `img.at<unsigned int>(r, c)` gives

```
1903260029 1533437542 ...
2004318088 ...
....
```

If I save the blurred image as a png file:

```
imwrite(lenablurgray1, 'lenablur.png');
```

Then when I read it in OpenCV:

```
Mat img = imread("lenablur.png");
img.convertTo(img, CV_64F);
```

then `img.at<double>(r, c)` gives

```
17 11 11 11 6
17 11 11 11 6
17 11 11 11 11
```

which still doesn't match the values from Matlab

**EDIT2**: I now see the values are wrong for the kernel. In Matlab, I get

```
imwrite(PSFgaussgray, 'PSFgauss.bmp');
disp(PSFgaussgray(7:9, 7:9)*256)

.0316 .0513 .0812
.0513 ...
...
```

whereas in OpenCV:

```
Mat kernel = imread("PSFgauss.bmp");
cvtColor(kernel, kernel, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
kernel.convertTo(kernel, CV_64F);

for (int r = 6; r < 9 ; r++) {
    for (int c = 6; c < 9; c++) {
        cout << kernel.at<double>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

The result I get doesn't match the values above:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: You cannot do `img.at<double>(r, c)` if you read in an image as `unsigned char` (BMP is always 8-bit unsigned integers).

Comment: what am I supposed to do then?

Comment: The type has to match the type of the data stored in the `img` object. See the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726

Comment: yes, I know that. I tried some changes in the EDIT, but those didn't work either

Comment: The BMP (and PNG too) are usually 8-bit unsigned integers, meaning you need to use `at<uchar>()`. You also have to make sure that the image is saved and read as gray-value images, not RGB. If `img` in OpenCV is RGB, the indexing changes too. Note how you see three identical consecutive values there, those are probably the 3 RGB components for one pixel. I don't know enough about OpenCV to help you with that.

Comment: Do note that MATLAB converts the double values in the range [0,1] to 8-bit unsigned integers in the range [0,255] when saving as BMP or PNG (or most other file types). So in OpenCV you should see  the same values as in MATLAB but multiplied by 255 and rounded.

Comment: displaying the values with `img.at<uchar>(r, c)` gave a bunch of strange characters

Comment: Oh, right, `cout <<` shows characters as characters, not their integer values. You can cast them to ints to show the numeric value: `cout << (int)img.at<uchar>(r, c)`.

Comment: That gives the same output I posted in the EDIT: `17 11 11 ...`. Those values can't be RGB because I saved the blurred image in Matlab with `lenablurgray1=mat2gray(lenablur1);`

Comment: See what `img.channels()` returns. I bet it is 3, not 1. A BMP file always contains an RGB image, AFAIK.

Comment: you're right, it was 3. I now converted it to grayscale with `cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` and I now get `164 170 176 176 181 ..`, which still do not match `0.5556    0.5778    0.6000    0.6222    0.6444`, even when those are multiplied by 256

Comment: One more change to make: MATLAB indexing starts at 1, OpenCV’s start at 0. You need to adjust the indices you use.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot about that. The results in OpenCV now match the ones in Matlab for the blurred image. However, the values for the kernel still do not match. I discuss this in EDIT2 in the original post

Answer (score 6):

To understand the discrepancy you see you need to know how MATLAB saves images to a BMP or PNG file, and how OpenCV reads it.

MATLAB assumes, if the image is of type `double` as is this case, that its intensity range is [0,1]. That is, pixel values below 0 and above 1 are not expected. Such images are multiplied by 255 and converted to 8-bit integers (which have a range of [0,255]) when saved to a file.

Thus, if

```
>> disp(lenablurgray1(91:93, 71:75))
0.5556    0.5778    0.6000    0.6222    0.6444
0.6000    0.6444    0.6667    0.6889    0.6889
0.6444    0.6889    0.7111    0.7333    0.7333
```

what is saved is

```
>> uint8( lenablurgray1(91:93, 71:75) * 255 )

142   147   153   159   164
153   164   170   176   176
164   176   181   187   187
```

Next, OpenCV will read this file as RGB (or rather BGR, OpenCV's awkward color order) and as 8-bit unsigned integer (`CV_8U`). To display these data, either extract one of the color channels, or convert to gray value using

```c++
cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

Then, read the 8-bit unsigned values with

```c++
img.at<uchar>(r, c)
```

If you read them with `img.at<double>()`, groups of 8 consecutive pixels will be regarded as a single pixel value (a `double` has 8 bytes).

Next, remember that MATLAB's indexing starts at 1, whereas OpenCV's starts at 0. So your loop should look like this:

```c++
for (int r = 90; r < 93; r++) {     // matches MATLAB's 91:93 indexing
    for (int c = 70; c < 75; c++) { // matches MATLAB's 71:75 indexing
        cout << (int)img.at<uchar>(r, c) << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
cout << '\n';
```

Finally, in the case of your kernel, note that its values, when multiplied by 255 are still much smaller than unity: `.0316 .0513 .0812`. These values will be written as 0 to the BMP or PNG file. If you want to save these values, you need to scale the kernel so its maximum value is 1:

```
PSFgauss = PSFgauss / max(PSFgauss(:));
imwrite(PSFgauss, 'PSFgauss.bmp');
```

(Note that this kernel is already a grey-value image, you don't need to use `mat2gray` on it.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, as I mentioned in EDIT3, I now notice that when I use `imfilter` in Matlab and `filter2D` in OpenCV, the values don't match. The values for `filter2D` seem wrong. Why is this?

Comment: @user5739619: please, please, don't make this question into a moving target. Please post this latest edit as a new question, you can link this question for reference. I'd be happy to answer it. Please include a MCVE, it is unclear what you are using as inputs to `filter2D`. Thanks!